# Running Amazon-Linux Docker Image on MacOS

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I was able to download amazon linux's image from this dockerhub -

```
ambakshi/amazon-linux    2016.03   083f32382cc4  4 months ago        142.7 MB
```

But I'm not able to do "yum install" any package on it. 
Keeps giving a 403 Forbidden error.

> [root@8ea0c348a91c /]# yum install lxml
>   Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
>   http://packages.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/2016.09/main/20160901f6a8/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml?instance_id=fail&region=URLError: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden"
>   Trying other mirror.

IS there something I'm missing?
I'm trying all of this in Mac OS. Can someone please help?

Thanks
Ramya

Comment: Is it possible that Amazon-Linux is Debian based? Have you tried apt-get install lxml?

Comment: 'yum' the package managerin Amazon-Linux. 'apt-get' is not present. (bash: apt-get: command not found )

Comment: Hmm... I was able to install it successfully on the same docker image when the image is running on a EC2 instance. But the same image when run on Mac OS does not allow 'yum install'. Seems like some permission issue.

Comment: or it could be a Docker bug?? What was the EC2 image that you were running? Can you do run a VirtualBox of that EC2 image (assuming it's freely available like CentOS, Fedora etc) on your Mac and then run your Docker container to isolate the issue? Well it's sort of like a dream-in-dream (remember Inception :-) ), but you will be able to narrow down the cause.

Comment: Tried this using Amazon's official docker image. No issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:

Amazon has now released official "Amazon Linux" Docker Images which can be used for local development:
Please check the details here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-linux-container-image-for-cloud-and-on-premises-workloads/

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/amazon_linux_container_image.html

Answer (score 0):

You can only download those packages if the container is running on Amazon's infrastructure within their network (an EC2 instance for example). It won't work from your local development machine.

Comment: About a week after this answer, this looks like it on premise use works:  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-linux-container-image-for-cloud-and-on-premises-workloads/